# Qt pop-up dialog to display information and close without expecting any user inputs

Tags: c++, qt, text, popup, qt5

[this is reference image of what i want, but i need the dialog without any buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5Gf.png) I have built a Qt application which has a feature to record video. I'm trying to add a popup window which says recording is done and closes itself after few seconds without expecting any input from user.

I tried using QMessageBox

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked() {
  count++;
  qDebug() << "count value" << count;
  if(count == 2){
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Video recording is done.");
    msgBox.exec();
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

I need a pop-up as above without any standard buttons.

Comment: Just run a timer and when it triggers close the dialog. PS: this is bad UI design.

Comment: The main concern is to have a dialog popup without any standard buttons. Just plain text information

Comment: @AA In this case, nothing prevents you to build your own dialog from a `QWidget` or a `QDialog` for example. `QMessageBox` is just a pre-built one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("Video recording is done.");

QTimer::singleShot(1000, [&msg]() { msg.close(); });

msg.exec();
```